# Filemanager laravel upload multiple images from

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to upload multiple images from Laravel Filemanager. I use `Unisharp` Filemanager, so since you cannot select multiple directly from filemanager, I want to select them one by one, and upload them into a container. From documentation, I use `$('#lfm').filemanager('image');`. So I made a `jQuery` script, which should create more imputs and images and put selected image into them, but it's not working properly. Even thought ids are changing, it always replace first image. What I'm doing wrong?
My code:
HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a id="lfm2" data-input="thumbnail1" data-preview="holder1" class="lfm2 btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Choose
                <input id="thumbnail1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="filepath2[]">
            </a>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="other_images_container">
            <img id="holder1" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:20px;max-height:100px;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var y = 2;

        $('.lfm2').click(function () {

            $('.lfm2').filemanager('image');

            var input = '<input id="thumbnail'+y+'" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="filepath2[]">';
            var image = '<img id="holder'+y+'" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:20px;max-height:100px;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;">';

            $(this).append(input);
            $('#other_images_container').append(image);
            $('.lfm2').attr('data-input', 'thumbnail'+y).attr('data-preview', 'holder'+y);
            y++;
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but hope this answer helps anybody.

You shouldn't use ID for lfm.
Use lfm in class, and use different **data-input and data-preview** for each upload button.

The best solution is to use class, so there are my CHOOSE's HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder" class="lfm btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> CHOOSE
        </a>
      </span>
      <input id="thumbnail" class="form-control" type="text" name="image" readonly>
    </div>
    <img id="holder" style="margin-top:15px;max-height:100px;">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a data-input="thumbnail2" data-preview="holder2" class="lfm btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> CHOOSE
        </a>
      </span>
      <input id="thumbnail2" class="form-control" type="text" name="image" readonly>
    </div>
    <img id="holder2" style="margin-top:15px;max-height:100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Than in javascript **this is jquery** :

```
<script>
    $('[class*="lfm"]').each(function() {
        $(this).filemanager('image', {prefix: route_prefix});
    });
</script>
```

hope anybody find the answer.